# Sending Devise Confirmation Mailer with Mandrill through My Rails App on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

I've got a Ruby on Rails app hosted with Heroku.

I'm using Devise for User Authentication. Trying to get Mandrill to send the Devise confirmation email.

I'm getting the following error in my heroku logs

```
Sent mail to EXAMPLE@gmail.com (23.4ms)
2015-02-04T00:38:02.334898+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 335ms
```

Note: the email is not being received by EXAMPLE@gmail.com.

Here's the code for Mandrill in my config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "example.herokuapp.com" }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port =>           '587',
  :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name =>      ENV['EXAMPLE@heroku.com'],
  :password =>       ENV['EXAMPLE'],
  :authentication => 'login',
  :domain => 'example.herokuapp.com'
}
```

EXAMPLE in the code above is actually replaced by my account information.

What am I missing?

Comment: In your config, are you using mandrill login credentials for ```:user_name =>      ENV['EXAMPLE@heroku.com'],
  :password =>       ENV['EXAMPLE'],```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up switching to SendGrid as a Heroku AddOn and it solved my problem.

Here's the code that ended up working for me in config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://www.EXAMPLE.com" }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => 'EXAMPLE',
    :password => 'EXAMPLE',
    :domain => 'EXAMPLE.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: switching to sendgrid is not a solution for the problem.